# How to understand the following output?

Tags: expect

I am working in the following expect code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect  
set string [lindex $argv 0]
send ${string}
send_user "$argv0 [lrange $argv 0 2]\n"
```

and i run this script like this:

```
newProves/expect$ expect arg.exp "THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  "
```

and i get the following output:

```
THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  arg.exp {THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  }
```

I have read in the documentation that expect has a list where stores the args, but my question is why if i am setting the argv0 to the string: "THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  ", then in the output prints:

```
arg.exp {THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  }
```

Which make me think that the argv0 is still the default name of the script, i would like to appreciate any explanation of this, and how is composed the list of the args of expect.

Comment: Where are you "setting the argv0 to the string" in that code?

Comment: in this line: set string [lindex $argv 0]

Comment: That's assigning to the variable `string` not assigning to `argv0`.

Comment: but how works? [lindex $argv 0] because i got confuse since i am using $argv 0 to assign the variable string

Comment: `set string [lindex $argv 0]` is `set`ting the value of `string` to be the value at `l(ist)index` `0` of the `argv` list. (i.e. `string=${argv[0]}` if this was shell.)

Comment: but why? when i run it in debug mode with -d i am getting this argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = arg.exp  argv[3] = THIS IS THE FIRST ARG

Comment: i am running this line expect$ expect -d arg.exp "THIS IS THE FIRST ARG  "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107196/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-user138717).

Comment: `lindex $argv 0` != `$argv0`. `$argv0`: usually the script name. `$argv`: arguments after the script, starting from 1 to the last. Often you don't need the program name, so splitting it this way is not a bad design decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting `argv0` anywhere in your script.

Expect sets it to the name of the script for you.

You can see this in the `expect -d` output:

```
$ cat arg.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect
set string [lindex $argv 0]
send ${string}
send_user "$argv0 [lrange $argv 0 2]\n"
$ expect -d arg.exp "THIS IS THE FIRST ARG "
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = arg.exp  argv[3] = THIS IS THE FIRST ARG
set argc 1
set argv0 "arg.exp"   # <-- This line sets `argv0` for expect.
set argv "{THIS IS THE FIRST ARG }"
executing commands from command file arg.exp
send: sending "THIS IS THE FIRST ARG " to { exp0 THIS IS THE FIRST ARG }
arg.exp {THIS IS THE FIRST ARG }
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra braces from from stringifying a list. The `lrange` command returns a list. The first element of that list is a string that contains whitespace, so when that list gets stringified, Tcl will enclose that element in braces:

```
% set argv [list "This is the first arg   " second_arg_with_no_whitespace]
% puts "hello [lrange $argv 0 end]"
hello {This is the first arg   } second_arg_with_no_whitespace
```

The solution is to convert that list to a string yourself:

```
% puts "hello [join [lrange $argv 0 end] " "]"
hello This is the first arg    second_arg_with_no_whitespace
```